# Heroku and Bigrock

Tags: heroku

I have purchased a domain from bigrock.in . I have a heroku app . Now I am trying to point heroku app to custom url.

I am getting dns target provided by heroku.

I am entering the same dns value as NAME SERVER in bigrock management portal.

Please correct me if there are any other steps to follow.I am stuck

Comment: Please narrow down your problem by specifying what exactly you're stuck on.

Comment: I dont know what to do next ....

Comment: I have performed steps as mentioned above

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?